# Some HTML buttons aren't working

Tags: html

I have a small website and it is complete. I am just a senior and it is just for a project on learning how to code. Everything works to perfection on the source computer that it was all coded on. I then exported the files and tried on several other computers. The files open up and everything looks okay, but two out of the five HTML buttons won't work. Is there a common reason why this is happening?

Comment: Without seeing any code, we wont be able to help you.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your code. Please add a [mcve] to your question. Thanks.

Comment: we would need to see some code so we can evaluate why it isn't working. Out of the gate, it is most likely that the file paths aren't correct. All depends on how you connected the file structure and if they are linking up properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the java function for the button

```
$('#createPassSubmit').click(function() {
                    var create = true;
                    var location = $('[name="reason"]').val();
                    var passnumber = $('#passnumber').val();
                    var note = $('[name="notes"]').val();
                    var student = $('#studentID').val();
                    var teacher = $('#teacherID').val();
                    var dataString = "CreatePass="+create+"&reason="+location+"&notes="+note+"&studentID="+student+"&teacherID="+teacher+"&passnumber="+passnumber;
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'ajax.php',
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(JSON.parse(data) === 'ERROR') {
                                alert("Pass " + passnumber + " is currently in use");
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#form input[type=text]').val('');
                                $("#form select").val('')
                                $('#sname').val('');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Then this is the HTML button its self

```
<input type="button" id="createPassSubmit" value="Create">
```